# Converting a hex to string in Swift formatted to keep the same number of digits

Tags: swift, string, int, hex

I'm trying to create a string from hex values in an array, but whenever a hex in the array starts with a zero it disappears in the resulting string as well.

I use `String(value:radix:uppercase)` to create the string.

---

An example:

Here's an array: `[0x13245678, 0x12345678, 0x12345678, 0x12345678]`.
Which gives me the string: `12345678123456781234567812345678` *(32 characters)*

But the following array: `[0x02345678, 0x12345678, 0x02345678, 0x12345678]` (notice that I replaced two `1`'s with zeroes).
Gives me the string: `234567812345678234567812345678` *(30 characters)*

---

I'm not sure why it removes the zeroes. I know the *value* is correct; how can I format it to keep the zero if it was there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number `0x01234567` is really just `0x1234567`. Leading zeros in number literals don't mean anything (unless you are using the leading 0 for octal number literals).

Instead of using `String(value:radix:uppercase)`, use `String(format:)`.

```
let num = 0x1234567
let str = String(format: "%08X", num)
```

Explanation of the format:

- The `0` means to pad the left end of the string with zeros as needed.
- The `8` means you want the result to be 8 characters long
- The `X` means you want the number converted to uppercase hex. Use `x` if you want lowercase hex.

Comment: Ah, great! Was exactly looking for this. I found Apple's string format specifiers but didn't know about the `0`, which I need.

Comment: But String(format:_:) needs to import Foundation, where String(_:radix:uppercase:) does not.